# APP crashes when remove KVO observer

Tags: ios, objective-c, key-value-observing

I have a scroll view in controller. The scroll view has one subview. The subview is an observer of the scroll view at the same time. I remove the observer when subview's `willMoveToSuperview:` called. But when the controller dismissed, app crashed. Here are the sample codes:

```
@interface MyView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIScrollView *scrollView;

@end

@implementation MyView

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame scrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.scrollView = scrollView;
        [scrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    [super willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];

    if (!newSuperview) {
        [self.scrollView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"];
        self.scrollView = nil;
    }
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
}

@end

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

    MyView *view = [[MyView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100) scrollView:scrollView];
    [scrollView addSubview:view];
}

@end
```

When I print `self.scrollView` in `willMoveToSuperview`, it shows null. When I change the property `scrollView` in MyView to unsafe_unretained, app will not crash.
So I am confused. Why not weak `scrollView` work. Am I reading dangling pointer when `scrollView` is unsafe_unretained? Are there better solution to that situation?

Comment: Wha is the crash? EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Comment: put remove code in @try catch

Comment: @AndreyChernukha the crash is the same as not calling `removeObserver:forKeyPath:`  
`2016-06-12 22:39:53.752 ScrollView[20987:7043889] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7fd01b824400 of class UIScrollView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7fd01a42ca60> (
<NSKeyValueObservance 0x7fd01a415330: Observer: 0x7fd01a4347d0, Key path: contentOffset, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property:>
)'
`

Comment: @sticker I don't think that works, because it did not crash around remove code.

Comment: @Rob `strong` reference will cause a retain cycle.

Comment: Agreed, `strong` will cause strong reference cycle. But `willMoveToSubview` is obviously too late in the tear down process.

Comment: @Rob Yes, may be `willMoveToSubview` should not be used to removeObserver.

Comment: @Bing were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is by the time `willMoveToSuperview` is called the `scrollView` `weak` pointer is already `nil`(deallocated).
But it think scrollView not completely deallocated(memory not released) thats why when you use `unsafe_unretained` reference to remove observer it works somehow. But it is a dangling pointer reference and you should not rely on that.

Comment: I think removeObserver in willMoveToSuperview may be a bad design.

Comment: yeah, you shouldn't observe any object for which you can't determine when it'll be deallocated.